# NSString regex string matching/search

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I have a string like @"random ++qwerty/asdf" and I want to fish out the qwerty part. The "random ++" and "/asdf" will always be the same. How would I go about doing this using regular expressions? I'm confused as to how they work.

Comment: [Here is a good resource.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) What have you tried?

Comment: i will take a look here, hte nsregularexpression documentation is really confusing

Comment: Admittedly, regular expressions are something that isn't intuitive enough to be easily learned from reading a documentation. However, if you take some time and read through the linked tutorial (at least the first few chapters) you'll get a really good grasp on it - and it's definitely valuable knowledge.

Comment: You could just use `-substringWithRange:`.

Comment: im looking to match that string first to make sure its the right format, and then fish out the qwerty part, substring doesn't do the matching as far as i know

Comment: `BOOL isRightFormat = [string rangeOfString: @"random ++"].location == 0;`

Comment: what about the stuff after the string i want? like the /asdf part, i need to make sure it matches @"random ++*/asdf" and get the * out

Comment: your /asdf is 5 chars long so length of the whole string - 5 chars would give you the location, and 5 is going to be the length for the NSRange...then you can match it with /asdf...I guess it's going to be easier than trying to come up with regex

Comment: whatever, i need to learn regex anyway so its not a big deal...does the xcode compiler need to escape the \ character? for example should i use \\+ for the +?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Problem Solved !!

This code give exactly what you want,

```
NSString *yourString = @"random ++qwerty/asdf random ++derty/asdf random ++noty/asdf";
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"random \\+\\+(\\w+)/asdf" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];


[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    // detect
    NSString *insideString = [yourString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

    //print
    NSLog(@"%@",insideString);

}];
```

Output: 
   **qwerty

   derty

   noty**

Comment: With so many resources available on regex usage, it still helps a lot to have concrete examples like this about specific types of matches! Thanks!